# startDate and endDate validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a validation between 2 dates, startDate and endDate, 2 inputs using jquery, my code from js

```
$('#start').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#end").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
    }
});

$('#end').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#start").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-fixer noEmpty" value="" id="start">

<input type="text" class="form-control form-fixer noEmpty" value="" id="end">
```

when i try to debug it doesn't even enter into `onSelect`, don't know what am i doing wrong, thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Could you place your code into jsfiddle for us?

Comment: your end datepicker is not properly closed. it is missing a '}' at the end.  $('#end').datepicker({
     onSelect: function(selected) {
         $("#start").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
     }
 });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `selected` text string being passed to the `onSelect` function isn't in the proper format for jQuery UI datepicker `minDate`.

You can use the text to create a new `Date()` object from this string that will be supported type for `minDate` ([here is the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)).

Also, I believe that you *probably* want to be setting the `maxDate` option for the **start date** when the end date is selected (in your example, you are setting `minDate` in both instances)

**Snippet:**

```js
$('#start').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
        $('#end').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(dateText));
    },
});

$('#end').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
        $('#start').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date(dateText));
    }
});
```

```css
div{
    padding: 15px;
    border: solid 2px steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div>Start: <input type="text" id="start" /></div>
<div>End: <input type="text" id="end" /></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm, also gonna check the documentation, gotta study lot more!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**  **With this user wont be able to pick a date before the start date**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="Stylesheet"type="text/css"/>
<style>
.mySelect {
    width: 300px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
      <td>
          From:
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" id="txtFrom" />
      </td>
      <td>
          &nbsp;
      </td>
      <td>
          To:
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" id="txtTo" />
      </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                var dt = new Date(selected);
                dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
                $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
            }
        });
        $("#txtTo").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                var dt = new Date(selected);
                dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
                $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```